# Custom Post Type Nav to Subpage

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, admin

I've registered a post type for an audio plugin, the post type is "Custom Players" in the admin and has its own tab on the admin sidebar.

I'm just curious if there's a simple way to move this out of the menu and make it another sub-item under "Settings", for example, as cleverly illustrated in this screenshot:

[image]

I know about the `show_in_menu` key for `register_post_type()` but don't want to make the post type inaccessible from the admin; I'm just curious about making it less prominent, it's a post type that won't be used frequently.

Thanks for even looking at this!
Peace

Comment: So you want to remove Haiku from under settings, and add it to under custom players? This sounds like you should modify the menu page registration for haiku players which you would need ot do in your code, and we cant advise on that here without more information or code to see

Comment: Hey Tom, thanks for the response. I'm trying to move "Custom Players" under the "Settings" tab, so that "Custom Players" would *look* like and be in the same list as "Haiku Player" (and the other Settings sub-items).

Answer (score 1):

You say that you know about `show_in_menu` parameter for `register_post_type()` but it seems like you missed the options for this parameter:

- 'false' - do not display in the admin menu
- 'true' - display as a top level menu
- 'some string' - If an existing top level page such as 'tools.php' or 'edit.php?post_type=page', the post type will be placed as a sub menu of that.

So, all you is set `show_in_menu` to `options-general.php` (top level settings menu):

```
add_action('init', 'cyb_custom_players');
function cyb_custom_players() {
    $args = array(
        'show_in_menu' => 'options-general.php',
        'label'        => 'Custom Players',
        'public'       => true
    );
    register_post_type( 'custom_player', $args );
}
```